# Boost. Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

```
class accel{
public:
    accel(int threads, string params);

private:
    void getfile(int from, int to);
    void download(int threads);
};


void accel::download(int threads){
    boost::thread g(&getfile(0, 1));  //<<<<
}
```

Gives an error '&' requires l-value. I have been doing this by example. How to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
boost::thread g (boost::bind(&accel::getfile, this, 0, 1));
```

Comment: And how to make one thread to wait for others to close before closing itself? Mutexes?

Comment: @gemexas: Make a new question.

Answer (score 2):

`getfile` returns `void`- you are trying to take the address of a variable of type `void`. That doesn't make any sense at all. You will have to use a bound function object- check out boost::bind.